# Plot of simulated distributions

Tags: r, distribution

I am doing research about the robustness in normal and gamma distributions with different parameters (sample sizes and variance.)

I also have been getting the simulated result. They are three tables. 
But now I have to try plotting simulated distributions to make people better understand the result.

I am still new in R. Do I need include all the three tables' result inside the plot of distributions?

```
########################################################################
#For gamma distribution with equal skewness 1.5

# rm(list=ls())  # clean the workspace
nSims<-10000       #set the number of simulations
alpha<-0.05        #set the significance level

# to ensure the reproduction of the result 
# here we declare the random seed generator
set.seed(1)

#create vector to combine all std deviations
sds<-matrix(c(4,4,6,4,8,4,10,4,12,4),nrow=2)

sd1<-c(4,6,8,10,12)
sd2<-c(4,4,4,4,4)

## Put the samples sizes into matrix then use a loop for sample sizes
 sample_sizes<-matrix(c(10,10,10,25,25,25,25,50,25,100,50,25,50,100,100,25,100,100),
 nrow=2)

#shape parameter for gamma distribution for equal skewness
#forty five cases for each skewness!!!!
sp1<-matrix(rep(c(16/9),each=45),ncol=1)

scp <- c(1,1.5,2,2.5,3)

##(use expand.grid)to create a data frame 
ss_scp<- expand.grid(sample_sizes[2,],scp)

#create a matrix combining the forty five cases of combination of sample sizes,shape and scale parameter
all <- cbind(rep(sample_sizes[1,], 5),ss_scp[,1],sp1,ss_scp[,2])

# name the column samples 1 and 2 and standard deviation
colnames(all) <- c("m","n","sp","scp")

#set empty vector of length no.of simulation(10000) to store p-value 
equal<-unequal<-mann<-c(rep(0,nrow(all)))

#set nrow =nsims because wan storing every p-value simulated 
#for gamma distribution with equal skewness
matrix_t <-matrix(0,nrow=nSims,ncol=5)
matrix_u<-matrix(0,nrow=nSims,ncol=5)
matrix_mann   <-matrix(0,nrow=nSims,ncol=5)

##for the samples sizes into matrix then use a loop for sample sizes
 # this loop steps through the all_combine matrix
  for(ss in 1:nrow(all))  
  {
   #generate samples from the first column and second column
    m<-all[ss,1]
    n<-all[ss,2]   

       for (sim in 1:nSims)
       {
        #generate 2 random samples from gamma distribution with equal skewness
        gamma1<-rgamma(m,all[ss,3],scale=all[ss,4])
        gamma2<-rgamma(n,all[ss,3],scale=1)

        gamma1<-gamma1-all[ss,3]*all[ss,4]
        gamma2<-gamma2-all[ss,3]

        #extract p-value out and store every p-value into matrix
        p<-t.test(gamma1,gamma2,var.equal=TRUE)$p.value 
        q<-t.test(gamma1,gamma2,var.equal=FALSE)$p.value
        r<-wilcox.test(gamma1,gamma2)$p.value 

        matrix_t[sim,1]<- p   
        matrix_u[sim,1]<- q 
        matrix_mann[sim,1] <- r
    }
       ##store the result
      equal[ss]<- sum(matrix_t[,1]<alpha)
      unequal[ss]<-sum(matrix_u[,1]<alpha)
      mann[ss]<- sum(matrix_mann[,1]<alpha)
  }

g1_equal<-cbind(all, equal, unequal, mann)
print("g1_equal_skewness1.5)")
print(g1_equal)

    #samples sizes (10,10),(10,25)..
  #standard deviation ratio (1,1.5,2,2.5,3)
                     Gamma(equal skewness)            Gamma(unequal skewness)
                    1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5     (1.5,1) 2,1.5 2.5,2 3,2.5 3.5,3
10,10
          Normal
    1.0     506     382 379 343  270     246        422 426 383 303   247
    1.5     472     493 463 507  537     571        531 518 548 528   532
    2.0    516      597 679 736  829     935        597 680 760 836   951
    2.5    498      627 747 905  1028   1215        687 825 944 1011  1197
    3.0    493      678 864 1010 1190   1379        705 831 1015 1170 1436


10,25

    1.0 511     568 557 633  647   630      603 599 604      652    654
    1.5 501     692 840 977  1012  1173     675 756 940     1068    1130
    2.0 438     713 951 1049 1264  1470     773 869 1055    1259    1401
    2.5 506     810 939 1101 1300  1594     761 960 1155    1339    1512
    3.0 524     787 933 1176 1378  1599     772 967 1201    1339    1612



25,25

    1.0 479     463 451 447 417 414     513 429 439 469 392
    1.5 493     534 556 504 568 587     537 517 528 539 555
    2.0 510     543 599 676 663 773     538 607 677 712 725
    2.5 487     591 662 731 807 908     581 643 733 769 893
    3.0 488     614 668 761 811 1002    582 694 728 900 946


25,50

    1.0 519     585 487 569 559 579     521 572 568 581 583
    1.5 510     532 651 695 725 836     625 647 729 737 802
    2.0 501     586 660 758 846 888     618 653 794 876 957
    2.5 466     635 687 823 937 996     612 702 782 909 1025
    3.0 492     603 719 824 970 1045    640 704 826 945 1073


25,100

    1.0 486     559 589 670 726  778    552 614 666 752 750
    1.5 494     621 700 787 903  955    602 703 774 842 1008
    2.0 516     617 707 817 969  1073   613 755 774 932 1091
    2.5 470     598 731 873 969  1118   624 752 849 970 1094
    3.0 493     710 718 824 1021 1167   645 746 887 988 1149

50,25

    1.0 495     507 511 552 550 534     491 527 496 554 534
    1.5 535     472 470 489 470 413     458 503 460 456 410
    2.0 499     507 478 488 468 465     495 490 542 528 489
    2.5 486     500 532 517 559 629     509 493 526 569 601
    3.0 490     586 536 561 654 644     544 567 563 614 665

50,100  1.0 518     515 530 531 514 569     516 494 517 548 578
        1.5 528     503 542 597 596 656     554 565 612 606 708
        2.0 453     525 588 640 727 775     520 625 628 727 772
        2.5 500     586 660 669 733 837     552 622 660 695 802
        3.0 494     557 640 680 747 847     582 634 686 776 834

 100,25                                                 
        1.0 489     553 607 641 712 777     557 560 653 677 751
        1.5 516     497 553 532 619 595     496 548 512 549 553
        2.0 500     492 483 518 472 468     536 521 497 463 463

        2.5 493     498 473 446 488 461     483 463 476 452 472
        3.0 482     490 516 481 488 500     563 477 496 492 537




 100,100
        1.0 472     508 492 483 517 487     517 521 476 505 485
        1.5 507     498 496 511 518 546     520 520 498 547 531
        2.0 465     478 540 542 584 599     496 504 585 558 589
        2.5 508     486 566 551 614 602     520 539 583 601 642
        3.0 494     497 575 545 614 651     561 557 590 615 624
```

Comment: The SO help pages ask for a "minimal" example. This can hardly be called "minimal" since it takes so long to compute. At the moment I couldn't tell whether you have created an infinite loop or just a really long-running program. I stopped execution of the nested for-loops at 6 minutes. which then allowed printing of the results which had reached row 34 of 45. You ought to improve your question by further editing to address that concern and the further concern that I cannot tell what sort of "plotting" you now anticipate or suggest. I only see one table so that needs clarification, too.

Comment: this is just one of the coding...I have another 10coding ...therefore I have eleven results

Comment: You do not seem to accepting advice intended to be helpful. Here's my effort to sharpen it to a fine point.  1) SHORTEN THE EXECUTION TIME and then 2) SAY WHAT TYPE OF PLOTS ARE NEEDED.

Comment: ermm...I am sorry .But i am struggling for it for quite a long time...sorry for giving you such a feel. I need  to plot a simulated distributions based on my simulated results (in gamma with equal skewness and unequal skewness and also in normal)

Comment: Still not at all clear to me anyway (remembering that I am _still_ unwilling to wait for hours to see your 11 "tables" and I do not yet see any edits). Do you want to show theoretic (or estimated) densities of cumulative distributions with the sample parameters from the tables, and if so, then what columns and rows should go with what theoretic parameters (or what portion of the code should be modified to allow a density estimate)????????

Comment: erm...sorry , i inserted one of my simulated results in above...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to know how to proceed with plotting your distributions.  You can create three separate plots, or you can overlay each distribution on one plot.  Here's how to do that in `ggplot2`.

Assume your dataframe is `df`, with columns `dist1`, `dist2`, and `dist3`.

```
install.packages('ggplot2')
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = dist1)) + 
    geom_density(color = 'red') +
    geom_density(aes(x = dist2), color = 'green') +
    geom_density(aes(x = dist3), color = 'blue')
```

This should give you a density plot with three lines, one for each distribution.  If you want to create three separate plots, simply create a new ggplot for each distribution.

```
plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = dist1) + geom_density()
plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = dist2) + geom_density()
```

... and so on.  Does this help?